# Keep list components alive in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a list of components that I render using `v-for`. Not all the components are shown simultaneously. I page the the array of rendered components by using `slice`.

These components shouldn't be rerendered, as some of them have user inputted data and some of them do network related tasks.

I tried to use `<keep-alive>`. However, this renders only the first component.

```
<keep-alive>
    <component :is="component.type" :key="component.id" v-for="component in components">
</keep-alive>
```

How do I keep a dynamic list of components alive?

Comment: by alive you mean to prevent re-render? Maybe by loosing observation on components? It is easy to do this way. Let me know if it could work for you

Comment: @MU Yes, I need to prevent re-rendering. What do you mean by losing observation on components?

Comment: What exactly is your problem, is it: `this renders only the first component` ?

Comment: @Saurabh Yes. Even though there are multiple items in the `components` array, only the first one is shown. It correctly retains its data, though, so it's not re-rendered.

Answer (score 6):

```
 <div v-for="comp in compList"  :key="'container'+comp.keyId" >
    <keep-alive>
      <component :is="comp.type" :key="comp.keyId"></component>
    </keep-alive>
 </div>
```

this above works for me . Pushing elements to compList correctly creates new instances of their respective components. Moving an element's index within the array , maintaining key,  does not call destroy/create and maintains state within each component

Comment: This works in Vue 3.

Answer (score 3):

Tested the answer above in a fiddle and doesn't work. https://jsfiddle.net/z11fe07p/680/

```
 <div v-for="component in myComponents"  :key="component.id" >
    <keep-alive>
      <component :is="component.type" 
               :name="component.name">
      </component>
    </keep-alive>
 </div>
```

Also i would avoid using vue reserved words such as `components` because there is a `components` key in the vue instance which tells what components the instance is using.

Comment: This is something I tried earlier but also noted it didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

There's note at Vue docs about your use case

> Note, `<keep-alive>` is designed for the case where it has one direct
> child component that is being toggled. It does not work if you have
> v-for inside it. When there are multiple conditional children, as
> above, ` requires that only one child is rendered at a
> time.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive

Try `v-once` directive instead.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-once

Answer (score 2):

I read source code of Vue's `<keep-alive>`, and I created new Component which works very well with list.

package name is `vue-keep-alive-global`. Here is a link, https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-keep-alive-global

How to use :

```
<KeepAliveGlobal>
    <YourComponent
        :key="uniqueKey"
    />
</KeepAliveGlobal>
```

With Array,

```
<template v-for="(item, index) of array">
    <KeepAliveGlobal :key="`blah-blah-${index}`">
        <YourComponent
            :item="item"
            :key="`your-component-${index}`"
        />
    </KeepAliveGlobal>
</template>
```

KeepAliveGlobal will cache component by key.